# $n$th derivative of $\exp\left({i \theta (q)}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Is there a general form for the $n$th derivative of $\exp\left({i \theta (q)}\right)$, where $\theta(q)$ is an arbitrary real valued function and $i$ is the imaginary number $\sqrt{-1}$?

I tried calculating up to the $10$th derivative but have not found any pattern.

Comment: What did you get for the first two derivatives?

Comment: first derivative: $i \theta '(q) \exp^{i \theta (q)}$ second derivative: $i \theta ''(q) \exp^{i \theta (q)}+ $(i \theta '(q))^2 \exp^{i \theta (q)}$

Comment: Given $f=e^{i\theta(q)}$ (abbreviated to $f=e^{i\theta}$) and using $\dot{f}$ and $\dot{\theta}$ to mean the first derivative of $f$ and $\theta$ with respect to $q$, then here are the first few derivatives:$$\begin{align}
\dot{f}&=e^{i\theta}(i \dot{\theta})\\
\ddot{f}&=e^{i\theta}(i^2\dot{\theta}^2+i\ddot{\theta})\\
\dddot{f}&=e^{i\theta}(i^3\dot{\theta}^3+3i^2\dot{ \theta }\ddot{ \theta }+i\dddot{ \theta} )\\
\ddddot{f}&=e^{i\theta}(i^4\dot{ \theta }^4+6i^3\dot{ \theta }^2\ddot{ \theta }+i^2(4\dot{ \theta }\dddot{ \theta }+3\ddot{ \theta }^2)+i\ddddot{ \theta })\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: So far I have at least spotted that the $n$'th derivative would have the form:$$\frac{d^nf}{dq^n}=e^{i\theta}\left(i^n\left(\frac{d\theta}{dq}\right)^n+i^{n-1}(\cdots)+i^{n-2}(\cdots)+\cdots+i\frac{d^n\theta}{dq^n}\right)$$